# Sharepoint Site Page Stop Anchor Link Scrolling Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

Salaamun Alekum

I Am Facing A Problem When I Click My Anchor Link A Function Is Called After Execution Of Function Complete Page Scrolls To Top Automatically Which I Do Not Want 
I Have Been Given This Page In Sharepoint

Here Are The Associated Codes

**Anchor Link**

```
<a id="lnkShowMoreColumns" href="javascript:;" class="add-filter-link">Add new filter...</a>
```

**On Click Binding**

```
$(".add-filter-link").click(addFilterRow);
```

**addFilterRow() Function Definition**

```
function addFilterRow(){
    var filterContainer = $(".filter-box-data");
    var filterRow = filterContainer.find(".filter-hidden").clone(true, true);
    filterRow.removeClass("filter-hidden");

    filterContainer.append(filterRow);
    filterRow.find(".logic-operator-container input[type='radio']").prop("name", "Operator" + filterContainer.find(".filter").length);
    return filterRow;
}
```

How To Stop Page From Scrolling To Top After Execution?

Thank You

Comment: The Page Is Not Refreshing / Reloading But Still Scroll Or Jumping To Top Again I Don't Know Why?

Comment: I think you should use your browser's `javascript debugger` to find out exact issue by using `breakpoints` in your script.

Comment: I Have Also Tried Testing With Button Instead To Anchor Link Still Its Scrolling Top Of Page
`<button type="button" id="button1" style="color: black;">Click Me!</button>`
And Script I Am Using To This
`$("#button1").click(addFilterRow);`

Comment: why are you returning `filterRow` to click event callback??

Comment: Thank You @IndrasinhBihola But I Am Debugging On `return filter` Its Executing Twice And After Return Page Scrolls To Top **Note** Page Is Not Refreshing And I Dont Want That Either I Just Also Don't Want Page To Scroll To Top

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola Because This Function Is Also Being Used Somewhere Else As
`$.each(selectedFiltersData, function(){

  var filterRow = addFilterRow();
  populateRowData(filterRow, this);
 })`

Comment: The return value of an event handler determines whether or not the default browser behavior should take place as well.

Comment: **@IndrasinhBihola** I Also Did Comment It Out ///return filterRow; But Still Its Scrolling To Top

Comment: `return false;` I Have Turned It To False Still Same Result Its Scrolling Up
I Also Even Tried This
`$(".add-filter-link").click(function(e) {
debugger;
addFilterRow();
e.preventDefault();

});`
But Result Remains The Same Its Scrolling Up To Top

Comment: No @IndrasinhBihola Its Not Scrolling With This Here I Have Recorded Steps [link]https://goo.gl/TYGPeJ

Comment: I Also Tried This Now Using Your Logic I Copied Function Code Placed It in Definition Of Click Function But Still Its Scrolling To Top

`$(".add-filter-link").click(function(e){var filterContainer = $(".filter-box-data");
 var filterRow = filterContainer.find(".filter-hidden").clone(true, true);
 filterRow.removeClass("filter-hidden");
 
 filterContainer.append(filterRow);
 filterRow.find(".logic-operator-container input[type='radio']").prop("name", "Operator" + filterContainer.find(".filter").length);e.preventDefault();});`

Comment: Test each statement one by one and test to find the exact cause of issue.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola I Presume I Happen On HTML Appending Via JQuery Because Recently I Tried Following HTML Append It Scrolled To Top Again 

`var filterContainer = $(".filter-box-data");
 html = '<div class="filter control-container column-container">Some HTML Code </div>';
    filterContainer.append(html);`

Comment: Put some html by update your question regarding your functionality so I can understand what you are trying to achieve when you click on add filter link.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola Here Is HTML Code [Link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/wc9kdfe8xil1x68/html.html?dl=0
Thank You **IndrasinhBihola**

Comment: I don't find `.filter-box-data` and `.filter-hidden` in your html.

Comment: I Have Saved Page Via [Ctrl]+[s]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uq0e2u7lc0tj884/Complete%20Page.zip?dl=0
@IndrasinhBihola Its Working Perfectly When Its Running Separately Without Sharepoint  But In Sharepoint Its Not Working Correctly Its Scrolling To Top

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola I Have Recorded A Video On The Issue Of The Behavior Here Is The [Video Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fzasvvguf2ezjf7/Recording.mp4?dl=0) https://www.dropbox.com/s/fzasvvguf2ezjf7/Recording.mp4?dl=0